# Why is IIS giving 403 with single quote in URL?

Tags: iis, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an ASP.NET (version 4) MVC 3 application running on IIS 7.5.  Anytime there is a single quote in the URL, for example http://devserver.com/myapplication/Home?filter=id~eq~'123' - I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Specifically, this happens when I'm using a Kendo UI grid and am trying to filter one of the columns.  But I found that anytime a single quote is in the URL, IIS immediately gives the 403 error.

I've looked in the IIS logs and the event viewer and there is no indication anywhere of a 403 response - I can't seem to find out specifically why the 403 was given.

Comment: Why do you have the single quotes there after all?

Comment: It's something Kendo UI does; I wouldn't have them in there if I could remove them.  It's how the Kendo UI filtering mechanism works.

Comment: I see. I've never worked with Kendo UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not IIS, it's Siteminder!  We have Siteminder in front of our web application, and Siteminder intercepts all incoming traffic for authentication.  In this case, Siteminder will also disallow a URL with a single quote in it.  Although the 403 error looks like it's coming from IIS, it's really coming from Siteminder.

Comment: I have the same problem? My firewall blocks the request. How did you get rid of it? is it possible to change it in KendoUI js or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened for my app as well and the culprit is Siteminder in my case.
They have a set of BadCSSChars lists which would be validated against our URL. If any bad character is found, the URL will be blocked and wont reach IIS.

Siteminder can remove the 'character needed' exception in the agent.log file (not an expert in this, but heard that this file which stores badcsschars list) in the app server.